# VS Code doesn't save new .ipynb files opened from the commandline in the specified location relative to the calling shell's cwd. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

So I have started using Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code but have run into the following problem: when I create a file via the terminal it doesn't save it in the directory from which the command was run and instead it creates it in the directory in which a file was last opened (in VS Code).

Example: the terminal is currently open in C:...\programs and so I use `code test.ipynb`. However, instead of creating a file there, it creates it in C:...\programs\files since the last file I opened manually in VS Code was from there.

(As a note, when doing this with .py files everything works perfectly.)

Comment: try `type # >.test.ipynb` followed by `code .\test.ipynb`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rioV8, but I can't get it to work. When I specify the path after writing the first command, it only outputs some information and doesn't change what happens when I try to save the file.

Comment: Oops, try `echo  # >test.ipynb` (mixed linux and windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I raised an issue ticket to the VS Code maintainers and they're on it now. There's not much else to do but wait for the fix to be made and released.

See the following:

- [`code new_file.ipynb` and then saving does not always honour the path of the new file #190703](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190703), which I raised
- [Multiple untitled notebook editors with same name but different associated path do not distinguish #191053](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191053), which was raised by the maintainers in relation to the issue ticket I raised above
- [Inactive notebook editor does not indicate dirty state in this case #191052](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/191052) raised by the maintainers possibly in relation to #191053.

I'm keeping an eye on those tickets and will update this answer post as things progress.