# 'Code' keyword in VS Code isn't creating a new notebook in the working directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, jupyter

If I do `pwd` in the VS Code terminal, I will get something like `path/to/directory`

When I then use the `code` keyword to create a new jupyter notebook like this:

`code textfile.ipynb`

It never creates the file in `path/to/directory`... It puts it in like a random directory I last visited or some other place. Is there some setting or something I'm doing wrong?

Edit: `touch textfile.ipynb` works just fine

Edit2: Same issue here [VS Code doesn't save .ipynb files in the open path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71924488/vs-code-doesnt-save-ipynb-files-in-the-open-path)

Comment: I observe similar behaviour. I have raised a bug ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190703 and will write an answer post to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71924488/11107541 with the findings from that issue ticket.

Comment: Yeah, can't be helped if it's just a bug